# When routing using router Link it creates the URL correctly but does not redirect to component and displays data?

Tags: typescript, angular-ui-router, angular7, angular-routing, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I face issue when route to component report details

using router link it only create URL link on browser but not redirect to

component report details until I click Enter.

It only working routing correctly if I use href .

If I use href or router link two both generate same URL link

```
http://localhost:4200/reportdetails?id=2028
```

If I use router Link I write router link as :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/reportdetails']" [queryParams]="{id: subrep.reportID}" >
```

When use href I write as below :

```
<a href="/reportdetails?id={{subrep.reportID}}">
```

approutingmodule.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo: 'ReportCategoryComponent', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path:'report',component:ReportCategoryComponent},
  {path:'reportdetails',component:ReportdetailsComponent},
  {path:'reportdetails/:id',component:ReportdetailsComponent}
];
```

so How to solve of issue of router link redirect ?

Comment: can you reproduce it? in example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-router-link?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: suppose i create new component and i need to save on stackbliz what i do to save

Comment: ok i do my stackbliz and save on the link

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-router-link-pcmw1c?file=src%2Fapp%2Freportdetails%2Freportdetails.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see that queryparams is added in the the link provided in `href` and `routerLink` but in routing module `id` is added a url param. It works with `href` as it reloads the component.

as per the route provided in routing module the url to a particular id should be `http://localhost:4200/reportdetails/2028`

for routing with url params you have to subscribe to `params` from `ActivatedRoute`
or to route with query params subscribe to `queryParams`

please find a routing demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvfex7?embed=1&file=src/app/data/data-detail/data-detail.component.ts) in stackblitz

Comment: can you please tell me how to subscribe param from activate route

Comment: adding a demo in stackblitz